# How do I save a dataframe with a list column of same-columned dataframes to parquet with arrow?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I have a dataframe with roughly 1200 columns, one of which is a list.  When using arrow::write_parquet(), all columns but the list column are detected correctly.  The list column has many NULL values.  The values that exist are dataframes themselves with five character columns (always with the same 5 names) and 1 to many rows. (It's possible if the 'NULL' values cause problems I could put zero-row dataframes in their places.)

Is there a way to specify a schema for the one list column and detect the rest of the columns so that I can save the dataframe to parquet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that even if you define a schema (`my_schema`) that includes the structure of the list column, `write_parquet(df,schema=my_schema)` will still fail if some of the rows of the list_column do not hold the same structure as the rows that do have that structure (i.e. if some of the rows are NA)

For example, if `dat` is a data.table with five, columns, one of which is a list column holding data.table...

```
     grp                data         a          b          c
   <num>              <list>     <num>      <num>      <num>
1:     1 <data.table[100x3]> 0.6142948 -1.0359482 -0.3782694
2:     2                  NA 0.1192991  0.1889432  0.2735809
3:     3 <data.table[100x3]> 0.4198558  0.6189989 -0.8201980
```

Then, `write_parquet(dat, schema=my_schema)` will fail (i.e. `Error: Invalid: Can only convert data frames to Struct type`).

I think the approach of placing a 0-row table of the same structure as the other tables in that list column is a good idea:

```
# get a null table of same structure
null_table = dat[!is.na(data)]$data[[1]][0,]

# replace the NA with the null_table
dat[is.na(data),data:=list(null_table)]

# write the parquet file
write_parquet(dat, "dat.pqt")
```

This is easily retrieved:

```
# Read the file
dat = read_parquet("dat.pqt")

# Convert the arrow list to data.table
dat$data= lapply(dat$data, data.table)

# Convert the data.tables with 0 rows back to NA
dat[sapply(dat$data,nrow)==0,data:=NA][]

     grp                data         a          b          c
   <num>              <list>     <num>      <num>      <num>
1:     1 <data.table[100x3]> 0.6142948 -1.0359482 -0.3782694
2:     2                  NA 0.1192991  0.1889432  0.2735809
3:     3 <data.table[100x3]> 0.4198558  0.6189989 -0.8201980
```

Comment: I suspect that may solve half the issue.  The other half though is do I need to manually define the other 2604 columns or is there a way to _just_ define the one column and infer the rest. (One issue with doing this is that while the list column stays constant, the others can come and go a bit based on the data so I'll need to define the other columns dynamically.)

Comment: Also, what are you using for 'my_schema'?  I'm getting the error "Error: Unrecognized vector instance for type ENVSXP" with
```
arrow::schema(
    a = arrow::struct(
            b = arrow::string(),
            c = arrow::string(),
            d = arrow::string(),
            e = arrow::string(),
            f = arrow::string()
        )
)
```

Comment: (also tried the above schema with `arrow::schema(a = arrow::list_of(arrow::struct(...)))` )

Comment: Sorry to confuse @Gabe, I don't think you need to define any schema if you simply use the approach where a 0-row table is placed in all the rows of that list_column that are NA

Comment: that way, you won't have to define any columns

Comment: write_parquet will generate a struct for the list_column, and will infer the type for the columns in that struct, and will infer the type for all the other 2604 columns

Comment: After testing I think you're right.  It can now correctly detect the list column schema.  Accepting this answer.  Thank you!